# replace div content jquery and show fontawesome icon

Tags: jquery, replace, font-awesome

I am writing a method to show fontawesome icons so the user can select one. When selected I want to change the content of a div with the name selected and also show the icon.

My jQuery function is

```
function changeSelected(boxName,name){
            var newText = "you have chosen " + name + " - <i class='fa-solid fa-" + name + "' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
            $('#' + boxName +'Chosen').text(newText);
          }
```

My problem is that it is showing the content with the code not the icon

[image: output sample]

Is there any way to show the icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .html(newText) instead of .text(newText)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that does not work, Just a square is shown

![blank] https://tdbforge.uk/square.png 

for a screenshot

Comment: It seems like the font-awesome css and font are not in the reference. Is the icon render properly with<i class='fa-solid fa-xxx'></i> direct in the html?

Comment: The css is there as it is showing the icons for the select list as you can see here ![list]https://tdbforge.uk.list.png.

Comment: The square means can't find the icon. Can you try inspect the output html? Copy the tag <i xxx></i> and paste in some place to see it the tag <i> working properly

Comment: I have sorted it. Instead of returning

<i class='fa-solid fa-" + name + "' aria-hidden='true'></i>

I got it to return <i class='fas fa-" + name + "' aria-hidden='true'></i>